# Recargar componente al pulsar en nav-tabs Angular con bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4

Es la primera vez que trabajo con nav-tabs de Bootstrap 4 y en mi componente he añadido esta sección de código la cual crea dos tabs con llamadas a otros componentes.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Sensores</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" (click)="borrartabs()" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Predicciones</a>
    </li>

</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
            <app-clima></app-clima>

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
        <app-predictions></app-predictions>
    </div>
```

El principal problema que tengo es recargar las tabs una vez que el usuario haga click sobre una de ella. Cuando el usuario está en la tabs de clima y cambia a las predicciones es necesario que el componente de predicciones vuelva a cargarse por completo de igual forma si cambiase a clima.

solo he visto documentación para mostrar una pestaña o ocultar otra pero no para recargarlas.

Este es el codigo que estoy probando para guardarlo en localsotrage cuando recargue la web saber donde estaba.

```
public probartabs() {

// dispose
  console.log('llM');
  //$('#exampleModal-sensor_grafica').modal('hide');
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
});

  let activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
  if(activeTab){
      $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
  }
}
```

¿Por otro lado es posible alguna forma de que solo se cargue el tabs que el usuario pulsa y no todos a la vez?

Gracias un saludo.

Comment: Que versión de angular estas utilizando ?

Comment: Hola, la version es Angular 6

Comment: Excelente, como estas utilizando comunicación entre componentes puedes declarar una variable del hijo en el padre y acceder al formulario y hacerle un reset() , cuando haga click en el tab

Comment: Hola, sería posible indicar un pequeño ejemplo? Sería con un input del padre al hijo y destruyendo el hijo?

Comment: Ya te deje la respuesta pruebala y me cuentas si te sirve

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te sirvió , si no por favor dejar el comentario para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

puedes probar algo como esto en tu **html** vas a declarar las variables de comunicación con los dos hijos así

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Sensores</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" (click)="borrartabs()" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Predicciones</a>
    </li>

</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
        <app-clima #variableHijo1></app-clima>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
        <app-predictions #variableHijo2></app-predictions>
    </div>
</div>
```

Como puedes ver se declararon las varables `#variableHijo1` y `#variableHijo2`.

Ahora en el componente padre el cual no subiste, entonces agregas lo siguiente:

```
@ViewChild('variableHijo1', { static: false }) variableHijoUnoComponent: HijoUnoComponent;
@ViewChild('variableHijo2', { static: false }) variableHijoDosComponent: HijoDosComponent;
```

Ahora tenes que crear un método para poder saber cuando hacen `click` en cada **tab** y obviamente saber en que **tab** se pararon para dar el `reset(),` entonces en tu código **html** vas a agregar lo siguiente:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true" (click)="limpiarTab(1)">Sensores</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" (click)="limpiarTab(2)" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Predicciones</a>
    </li>

</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
        <app-clima #variableHijo1></app-clima>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
        <app-predictions #variableHijo2></app-predictions>
    </div>
</div>
```

Si te fijas en los `ul > a` de los **tabs** agregue el método `limpiarTab()` y envió un números lo puedes cambiar por lo que quieras.

ahora creas ese metodo de la siguiente forma en el cual vas a acceder a los formularios de cada uno de los componentes:

```
limpiarTab(tabSeleccionado) {
    if (tabSeleccionado === 1) {
      this.variableHijoUnoComponent.variableTuyaFrom.resert();
    } else {
      this.variableHijoDosComponent.variableTuyaFrom.resert();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hola tengo algunos problemas:
1º un eror aqui { static: false })
2º en el metodo limpir es resert? o sin la t ademas la variableTuyaFrom que seria?
gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Que error te arroja en el **Static** ? y segundo si va con la **T** y tercero , la `variableTuyaForm` seria la variable con las que recuperas los datos del formulario, te doy un ejempo real seria algo como esto `public financieraFrom: FormGroup;` y lo tendrias incializado de esta forma  `this.financieraFrom = new FormGroup({`

Comment: Estas utilizando la version 6 de angular , creo que esto `, { static: false }`lo debes de borrar

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar `*ngIf` para evitar que los componentes se rendericen hasta que cambies una variable:

```html
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
    <app-clima *ngIf="mostrarClima"></app-clima>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">

    <app-predictions *ngIf="mostrarPredictions"></app-predictions>

  </div>
```

## [`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

> Una directiva estructural que incluye condicionalmente una plantilla basada en el valor de una expresión forzada a booleana. Cuando la expresión se evalúa como verdadera, Angular representa la plantilla proporcionada en una cláusula `then`, y cuando es falsa o nula, Angular representa la plantilla proporcionada en una cláusula `else` opcional. La plantilla predeterminada para la cláusula `else` está en blanco.